# How to make heading speed up per click using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it to where everytime you click the heading it speeds up. However it either speeds up for the first few click or starts to become extremely slow. I have also tried changing the sign of *= 999 to += and -= and i do not find any different results. Please help.

```js
var x = 10000
  //x is the speed of animate
  //this is where the movement is defined for the heading
function move() {
    $("h1").animate({
      "left": "+=200px"
    }, x).animate({
      "top": "+=200px"
    }, x).animate({
      "left": "-=200px"
    }, x).animate({
      "top": "-=200px"
    }, x);
  }
  //this should make the heading move faster
$("h1").click(function() {
  move()
    //this should make it move faster
  x *= 999
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="heading" style="position:absolute;">Watch the moving heading!</h1>
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS applied to the header? Can we see that too?

Comment: Why would CSS be relevant at all?

Comment: I want to know, for example, if the header is absolutely positioned with an already defined/top value.

Comment: The problem here is that you're setting the animation duration to 10000; changing `x` after the fact won't change the duration of animations already in the queue.  You would need to stop the existing animation and start a new one with a shorter duration -- matching this to motion already in progress would be fairly difficult.  You'd probably be better off setting the element position `+=x` (for small values of x) in a loop, rather than depending on `.animate` here -- that'd allow you to usefully update x on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `x` tells how long your animation takes to complete. So `10000` means `end after 10s` while `90000` means `end in 90s` - bigger means slower.

Instead of increasing time (`*=`, `+=`, `++`) you need to decrease it (`/=`, `-=`, `--`)

I also added `.finish()` to complete current animation and start for beginning, you can remove it if you like.

```js
var x = 10000;

function move() {
    $("h1").finish().animate({
      "left": "+=200px"
    }, x).animate({
      "top": "+=200px"
    }, x).animate({
      "left": "-=200px"
    }, x).animate({
      "top": "-=200px"
    }, x);
  }

$("h1").click(function() {
  move();
  x -= 500;
  x = Math.max(1, x);
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="heading" style="position:absolute;">Watch the moving heading!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to note.

**1)** To increase the speed of animation you must decrease the time taken for animation. So you need something like `x -= 300;` and **not** increase it by doing `x *= 999`

**2)** Finish off the existing animation and start a new when clicked the `h1`. Use `.finish()` to finish the running animation.

**3)** move away 200 pixels from left, then move away 200 pixels from top, Now you must move back to the original position and not -200 from the original position, you must use `left:0px` and `top:0px`to move back to initial position.

Check the working demo.

```js
var x = 1000

  //x is the speed of animate
  //this is where the movement is defined for the heading
function move() {
   
    $("h1").finish().animate({
      "left": "200px"
    }, x).animate({
      "top": "200px"
    }, x).animate({
      "left": "0px"
    }, x).animate({
      "top": "0px"
    }, x);
  }
  //this should make the heading move faster
$("h1").click(function() {
  move();
    //this should make it move faster
    if(x > 100) x -= 300;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="heading" style="position:absolute;">Watch the moving heading!</h1>
```